# How to compare if a char* is greater than or equal to another string/number?

Tags: c

I'm using scanf to input numbers and +,-,/ operators into a stack.

```
int scan = 1;
char * p = malloc(sizeof(char)*5);
while (scan = 1) {
    scanf("%1s", p);
    if(p>='0' && p<='9'){
        push(stack, p);
        print(stack);
    }
}
```

Why does it never meet the condition? How can you compare strings?

Comment: pretty sure you're comparing the pointer-value (offset of data in memory) to `'0'` rather than the character itself (`*p`)

Answer (score 2):

Well, if what you want to do is test whether the first character of the string is between '0' and '9', you should do:

```
(*p >= '0' && *p <= '9')
```

But if you want to compare strings as strings, the old school C library function for that is `strcmp`.  I'm sure these days there are lots of other libraries that may offer more functionality.

Comment: Thank you, I'm still trying to fully wrap my head around pointers haha. First year computer eng student and everythings moving so quick.

Whats the difference between comparing *p with '9' and p with '9'

Comment: `p` is a pointer variable.  The value it actually contains is the address of another location in memory.  That's the value you are using when you simply write `p`.  `*p` means to get the value in the location that p points to.  In this case, since the type of `p` is `char *`, it would read `sizeof(char)` bytes at that location.

Answer (score 1):

`if(p>='0' && p<='9'){`

`p` is a `char*`, `'0'` is a char. Your compiler should have warned you about comparing incompatible types. Use `*p`  instead (same applies to `'9`' obviously). In my head `*p` gets read as "contents of p" (in this context)

In the more general case, use `strcmp()` to compare strings.

If your compiler did warn you about the bad compare: take it on board, most compiler warnings should be listened to and not ignored. If your compiler didn't warn you look up how to enable all the warnings.